# Openstack Horizon Fetch Instances

Tags: openstack

I would like to fetch all instances and calculate the uptime of the vcpu ram etc.

upon checking out the existing horizon code which sits at openstack_dashboard/dashboard/usage

```
usage = api.nova.usage_get(self.request, self.tenant_id, start, end)
```

I have searched the internet for a documentation for it but i am so unlucky to find one. ,
I would like to know what will be in the arguments start and end.

Thanks, I hope someone who could lead me into this.

Comment: My best guess it its  start and end dates during which you want usage data.

Comment: I am probably the guy who wrote that.  And yeah, I completely forget.

Comment: If you can get into a django debug output... you SHOULD be able to pull out that info.

Comment: Have you looked at the OpenStack Ceilometer component?  It provides detailed usage information in V2 of the reporting API.

Comment: I don't believe there is currently a ceilometer interface in horizon.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your horzion with `./manage.py shell`